# C++ writing string to file = extra bytes

Tags: c++, string, file, filesize

I am using c++ to look through 256 counts and write the ASCII representative to a file.

If i use the method of generating a 256 character string then write that string to the file, the file weighs 258bytes.

```
string fileString = "";

//using the counter to attach the ASCII count to the string.
for(int i = 0; i <= 256; i++)
{
    fileString += i;
}

file << fileString;
```

If i use the method of writing to the file withing the loop, the file is exactly 256bytes.

```
//using the counter to attach the ASCII count to the string.
for(int i = 0; i <= 256; i++)
{
    file << (char)i;
}
```

Whats going here with the string, what extra information from the string is being written to the file?

Comment: You have an off by one error in your loop. It should be != 256 or < 256. You are getting the value 256 into the string and that doesn't fit in one byte. I'd have thought it should be giving you a compile error. Oh, and don't use C style casts in C++, that is masking the problem for your second example.

Comment: everything compiles and works. The last method with the casting makes the file a perfect 256byte. Which is what the file should be right?

Comment: You still have an off-by-one error. There is no 256th ASCII character, only 0-255. Also, Kay, the += will do the cast automatically, wrapping back around to 0 at 256.

Comment: So that brings the file size down to 257 bytes. Is that normal for a file thats holding 256 characters?

Comment: Perhaps as text, as binary it should match exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of these create a 256 byte file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::ofstream file("output.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::string fileString;

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        fileString += static_cast<char>(i);
    }

    file << fileString;
}
```

And:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::ofstream file("output.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::string fileString;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        file << static_cast<char>(i);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Note, before you had an off-by-one error, as there is no 256th ASCII character, only 0-255. It will truncate to a char when printed. Also, prefer `static_cast`.

If you do not open them as binary, it will append a newline to the end. My standard-ess is weak in the field of outputs, but I do know text files are suppose to always have a newline at the end, and it is inserting this for you. I think this is implementation defined, as so far all I can find in the standard is that "the destructor can perform additional implementation-defined operations."

Opening as binary, of course, removes all bars and let's you control every detail of the file.

---

Concerning Alterlife's concern, you can store 0 in a string, but C-style strings are terminated by 0. Hence:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string result;

    result = "apple";
    result += static_cast<char>(0);
    result += "pear";

    std::cout << result.size() << " vs "
        << std::strlen(result.c_str()) << std::endl;
}
```

Will print two different lengths: one that is counted, one that is null-terminated.

Comment: i < 255. Wont that write up to 0 - 254?, If I do 'i < 256' That will include the 255th character and I'll get the file size of 256bytes?

Comment: I did that and my text file came up to 257bytes. Any idea whats that extra byte for?

Comment: visual studio, empty c++ project, windows vista, not sure about the binary mode. I'm going to try that.

Comment: Ok. Binary gives you complete control over the file, byte for byte. otherwise, in text mode, it seems the compiler can add whatever it wants. If you really need per-byte control, you'd want to do binary anyway.

Comment: binary file is 256, txt file is 257.

Comment: Anytime, that extra byte is probably the new-line. Explains everything.

Comment: And you can of course check this by opening the file in binary mode, then checking each byte. The last one would be `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

im not too gud with c++ but did you try initializing the filestring variable with null or '/0' ?? Maybe then it will give 256byte file..

N yea loop should be < 256

PS: im really not sure but then i guess its worth trying..